# Sending HTTP POST with System.Net.WebClient

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, webclient

Is it possible to send HTTP POST with some form data with System.Net.WebClient?

If not, is there another library like WebClient that can do HTTP POST? I know I can use System.Net.HttpWebRequest, but I'm looking for something that is not as verbose.

Hopefully it will look like this:

```
Using client As New TheHTTPLib
    client.FormData("parm1") = "somevalue"
    result = client.DownloadString(someurl, Method.POST)
End Using
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Based on @carlosfigueira 's answer, I looked further into WebClient's methods and found [**UploadValues**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f.aspx), which is exactly what I want:

```
Using client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    reqparm.Add("param1", "somevalue")
    reqparm.Add("param2", "othervalue")
    Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues(someurl, "POST", reqparm)
    Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
End Using
```

The key part is this:

```
client.UploadValues(someurl, "POST", reqparm)
```

It sends whatever verb I type in, and it also helps me create a properly url encoded form data, I just have to supply the parameters as a namevaluecollection.

Comment: What does `someUrl` refer to?? I'm trying to log in to a website that has a HTML login-form, it doesn't login. The resulted data is as if I'm anonymous.

Comment: @Shimmy I haven't tried using webclient on a site that requires login. `someUrl` is URL string, for example `client.UploadValues("http://localhost", "POST", reqparm)`.

Comment: can we use this POST request (including the parameters call) with the asynchronous call?

Comment: It's working fine, thanks for the answer! But when I call `Net.WebClient.UploadValues` method it's start 7 threads and don't stop these. What could I do about this?

Answer (score 14):

`WebClient` doesn't have a direct support for form data, but you can send a HTTP post by using the UploadString method:

```
Using client as new WebClient
    result = client.UploadString(someurl, "param1=somevalue&param2=othervalue")
End Using
```

Comment: POST - that's the default for `UploadString`. You can also pass the HTTP verb as an optional third parameter.

Comment: I guess the form data needs to be escaped: `"param1=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode("somevalue")`

Comment: If the value needs to be escaped, yes. "somevalue" doesn't. As I mentioned, `WebClient` itself doesn't have any form support, you need to create the string yourself.

Comment: Based on your answer, I found UploadValues. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing it :)

Comment: If you use UploadString to post form values make sure to include client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").

Comment: uploadvalues of course works at the moment i wrote this comment. But is it possible as well for downloading a file?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the http verb is concerned the `WebRequest` might be easier. You could go for something like:

```
    WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create("http://some.url");
    r.Method = "POST";
    using (var s = r.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(r, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Obviously this lacks exception handling and writing the request body (for which you can use `r.GetRequestStream()` and write it like a regular stream, but I hope it may be of some help.

Comment: question has tag `vb.net`