# Adding Certificate to WebClient

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient, x509certificate

I want to send out a POST with a specific certificate using WebClient. Request you to kindly help. I want something like this.

```
Dim  myWebClient As New WebClient()
mywebclient.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate()
Dim responseArray1 As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues(finalurl1, "POST", myNameValueCollection1)
```

Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here: [How can you add a Certificate to WebClient (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066489/how-can-you-add-a-certificate-to-webclient-c)

Converted to VB (untested):

```
Public Class MyWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim R = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        If TypeOf R Is HttpWebRequest Then
            With DirectCast(R, HttpWebRequest)
                .ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate())
            End With
        End If
        Return R
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Femiani..I got to know how to add certificate to webclient but I am not sure how to use this for executing someurl.i nned to execute something like this                              Dim responseArray1 As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues(someurl, "POST", myNameValueCollection1)

Comment: @user3631589 This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222092/sending-http-post-with-system-net-webclient. I highly recommend you search for the answers to your questions before asking repeats, you'll be amazed how much information is already out there. Good luck.