# Call a web service from a desktop application in c#

Tags: c#, forms, web-services

I want to call a web-service, Post method from my desktop application in c#.
My html form for post method is:

```
<form name="codfiscalForm" method="POST" action="/numeCod.html">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="text3">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="33%">


              &nbsp;Judetul:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-display-name="cod" s-data-type="Number" s-number-separators="x," b-value-required="TRUE" i-minimum-length="1" i-maximum-length="10" s-validation-constraint="Greater than or equal to" s-validation-value="1" s-validation-constraint="Less than or equal to" s-validation-value="9999999999" -->


              <select name="judet" size="1" class="form2">

                <option value="40">BUCURESTI</option>

                <option value="01">ALBA</option>

                <option value="02">ARAD</option>

                <option value="03">ARGES</option>

                <option value="04">BACAU</option>

                <option value="05">BIHOR</option>

                <option value="06">BISTRITA-NASAUD</option>

                <option value="07">BOTOSANI</option>

                <option value="08">BRASOV</option>

                <option value="09">BRAILA</option>

                <option value="10">BUZAU</option>

                <option value="11">CARAS-SEVERIN</option>

                <option value="13">CONSTANTA</option>

                <option value="51">CALARASI</option>

                <option value="14">COVASNA</option>

                <option value="12">CLUJ</option>

                <option value="15">DIMBOVITA</option>

                <option value="16">DOLJ</option>

                <option value="17">GALATI</option>

                <option value="52">GIURGIU</option>

                <option value="18">GORJ</option>

                <option value="19">HARGHITA</option>

                <option value="20">HUNEDOARA</option>

                <option value="21">IALOMITA</option>

                <option value="23">ILFOV</option>

                <option value="22">IASI</option>

                <option value="24">MARAMURES</option>

                <option value="25">MEHEDINTI</option>

                <option value="26">MURES</option>

                <option value="27">NEAMT</option>

                <option value="28">OLT</option>

                <option value="29">PRAHOVA</option>

                <option value="30">SATU MARE</option>

                <option value="31">SALAJ</option>

                <option value="32">SIBIU</option>

                <option value="33">SUCEAVA</option>

                <option value="34">TELEORMAN</option>

                <option value="35">TIMIS</option>

                <option value="36">TULCEA</option>

                <option value="37">VASLUI</option>

                <option value="38">VALCEA</option>

                <option value="39">VRANCEA</option>
                        </select>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="29%">Numele:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-display-name="nume" s-data-type="String" b-allow-letters="TRUE" b-allow-digits="TRUE" b-allow-whitespace="TRUE" s-allow-other-chars=". , ? &quot; &quot;" b-value-required="TRUE" i-minimum-length="2" --> 
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form2" size="15">

        </td>
            <td width="38%"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="form1" value="VIZUALIZARE"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="33%">
        &nbsp;</td>
            <td width="29%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="38%">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="33%">
        &nbsp;</td>
            <td width="67%" colspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

So, I have 2 inputs, one for the adress and one for company name. How can I implement a post method with 2 inputs in my desktop application. For example, I will have a dropdownlist and a textbox. How can I use these to call post method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST with System.Net.WebClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222092/sending-http-post-with-system-net-webclient)

Comment: try to search in youtube or any site.

Answer (score 0):

you can use submit button to post a from.
Suppose your service is like

```
 public void SampleService(string textboxid,string dropdownid)
   {
   }
```

You have to give textboxid,dropdownid as Id attributes for your html controls.

Comment: Need more help?

Comment: do you mean the name for inputs, judet and name?

Comment: You are using MVC application?

Comment: consider i have a win form with 2 inputs, i wan only to call that web service and display the response into a list